# Open Access Form based on multiple values

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two forms. One connects to a table and is used to enter, change and view entries.
From the second form I want to open the first form to a certain record.

Table contains records for 6 different items, but there are multiple records for each item. A new one is added when old record is marked as closed (true/false tick box.

I can create the code for opening a record based on just the number of item, but am unable to add the checkbox consideration.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", , , "Form1.[Variable]=" & Me![Combo4]
```

This reads the number from a dropdown menu box on Form2 and opens Form1 with that value.
Now I need to add another condition to the open command.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", , , "Form1.[Variable]=" & Me![Combo4] And "Form1.[Variable2] <>" & Me![Checkbox]
```

This should open only the record for a certain numbered item and only the record that hasn't been closed yet (I included a hidden checkbox on Form2 to use same Me![] command, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some quotes to manage:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", , , "Form1.[Variable] = " & Me![Combo4] & " And Form1.[Variable2] <> " & Me![Checkbox] & ""
```